# How to find negative imaginary parts of values in an array then turning them to positive?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have a function `a=x*V` where `x` assumes thousands of values as `x = arange(1,1000,0.1)` and `V` is a combination of other constants. These make `a` always complex (has nonzero real and imaginary parts). However, because `a` depends on other values, the `imag(a)` can be negative for some `x`'s.

For what I am doing, however, I need `imag(a)` to be always positive, so I need to take the negative values and turn them into positive.

I have tried doing

```
if imag(a)<0:
    imag(a) = -1*imag(a)
```

That didn't seem to work because it gives me the error: `SyntaxError: Can't assign to function call`. I thought it was because it's an array so I tried `any()` and `all()`, but that didn't work either.

I'm out of options now.

Comment: Can you not use absolute value? That will just make it positive, no if statements required

Comment: What package are you using for complex numbers?  It's not the native Python `complex` package, as that doesn't provide `imag()` as a function.  That directly uses `a.imag` for both LHS and RHS references.

Comment: @George_E That doesn't really solve my problem as the real part still needs to be whatever it is. I don't use them separately. But I still need the imaginary part to be always positive. So I basically need to go inside q, change the negative imaginaries to positive and then use q elsewhere. If that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [35]: a = np.array([1+1j, 2-2j, 3+3j, 4-4j])

In [36]: a.imag *= np.where(a.imag < 0, -1, 1)

In [37]: a
Out[37]: array([ 1.+1.j,  2.+2.j,  3.+3.j,  4.+4.j])
```

Comment: Hi That's seems to sort it, somewhat... What is the -1 and 1 in line 36 mean ?

Comment: @Mac, we are multiplying the `image` part of complex numbers to `1` if it's not negative (i.e. it remains the same) or to `-1` if it's negative

Answer (score 0):

You can't redefine a function that way. It would be like saying

```
sqrt(x) = 2*sqrt(x)
```

What you can do is reassign the value of `a` (not `imag(a)`).

```
if imag(a) < 0
    a = a - 2*imag(a)*j
```

For example, if `a = 3 - 5j`, then it would give you

```
3 - 5j - 2(-5)j = 3 + 5j
```

Comment: @Mac Not very familiar enough with python so I'll have to say no. :(

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be faster than doing subtraction. For a full function:

```
import numpy as np

def imag_abs(x):
    mask = x.imag < 0
    x[mask] = np.conj(x[mask])
    return x
```

Comment: @Mac I guess if you don't include it in a code block then copypaste destroys python indentation...